# Sqoop import for hadoop 2.5.0

Tags: couchbase, sqoop, hadoop-plugins

**Problem:**

Sqoop import failing due to wrong combinations of sqoop plugin, hadoop and couchbase connector.

**Details:**

I am using **Sqoop 1.4.5-cdh5.2.0** with **Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.2.0** on a Linux machine having java 6 for importing data from couchbase using **couchbase plugin 1.1.dp3**.
But sqoop jobs fail.

I have tried with the earlier versions of sqoop like Sqoop 1.4.3 and 1.4.4. These versions have problems related to password. So any bucket having a password, import fails.

Please suggest the best & working combination of Sqoop version, hadoop and couchbase plugin which is working for anyone.
Running combinations of the above over past few days and not going anywhere.

Any help appreciated !
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw this issue live with Couchbase 2.2 and Sqoop 1.4.5. I upgraded the couchbase libraries and edited the source code to make it work. I have posted in git hub the entire folder.

https://github.com/arungeorge81/sqoop-couchbase-pass-fix